# Unable to compare password stored in MySQL database with password entered from front end using bcrypt

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I'm entering a password from front end inside MySQL for registered user. Now when im signing in I wish to compare the entered password with original stored password in database using bcrypt-nodejs. But unable to do so. Im a beginner at Node.js, please help !!

this code is in my server.js file which is the main node server file.

```
app.post('/signin', (req,res)=>{

     const {email} = req.body; 
      let post= {email: email};

      let sql= 'SELECT password FROM users WHERE email= ?';
      let query= db.query(sql, post,(error,result)=>{

    if(error) 
    {
        throw error;

    }

    else if(!error)
     {  

     bcrypt.hash(result, null,null, function(err,res){


      });


     bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, hash, (err,res)=>{

        if(err)
        {
            throw error;
        }
         else if(res)
          {
            res.send('signin successful');
          }
     }

      else {
        res.status(400).json('error logging in');
      }
       //res.json('signin');  

      });

      })


  })
```

as you can see, Im trying to hash the result which is the password from the database and compare it with req.body.password which user enters from front end, but Im getting error in my console

Comment: What error? You don't have to hash `result` when verifying the password, it should be stored hashed already.

Comment: Don't store the password as a string in dd which is unsecured. Try to store the hashed password in DB and try comparing the hash with the password typed. Side Node - don't create your login system you could use cognition or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite a little with `async/await` to make it more readable

```
app.post('/signin', async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  let post = { email: email };

  let sql = 'SELECT password FROM users WHERE email= ?';
  const queryResult = await new Promise(resolve => db.query(sql, post, (error, result) => resolve(result)));
  // I assume you should access here your hash with something like this queryResult.password`
  const hashStoredInDb = queryResult.password;
  const compareResult = await new Promise(resolve => bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, hashStoredInDb, (err, res) => resolve(res)));

  // Your other verification logic based on compare result.
})
```

So, the main logic is to compare hashed password already stored in db with provided from user.

Also, you could add some verifications in provided code, I've missed some `try/catch` for simplicity and readability.

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me in just check the database column length its definitly greater that 70 or not in case lower than 70 increase the length

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).